# F# function in module showing "Method Not Found" when called from a namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, f#

I have a function defined in a module called DataAccess like this

```
module DataAccess
let getData() = 
    ["abc";"def"]
```

I'm then using an F# MVC controller to pull the data out like this

```
[<HandleError>]
type FitnessController() = 
    inherit Controller()

    member x.Index() =
        let data = DataAccess.getData() |> List.map(fun p -> p) |> List.toArray
        x.View(data) :> ActionResult
```

I get intellisense and all builds well, but when the web page pops up it says that the method does not exist

```
Method not found: 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<Models.Entity> DataAccess.getData()'.
```

When I take a look at the assembly in dotPeek it does show up as a static method that returns an FSharp list. Am I missing something obvious here?

(Ignore the fact that getData and the map function do nothing i've omitted the code for brevity, getData just contains record types that are marked as serializable, but I still get the error even when using strings as in the code example here) I should also say that this is MVC 3 with Razor C# pages.

Comment: oddly enough I tried to wrap it into a type in a namespace and still got the same error. The list gets passed into JSon action result and the type that's being returned is marked as serializable. If I hand code a list and pass it into the JSon constructor all works as expected

Comment: Have you checked the compilation order - you will need to have the file with DataAccess before the other file

Comment: yeah build order is ok. It's a run time issue which makes me thinks it's something odd with F# and MVC

Comment: The implementation of the `Index` method as shown in the question seems wrong - if the body is just `let`, then it is not syntactically valid. It needs to return something (i.e. a `View`?) Can you show the actual code?

Comment: There is another slight error in the code - you need to use `List.map (fun p -> p)`.  Fixing this it works fine for me in the interactive.  Perhaps one of the F# DLL files is missing?

Comment: Hi John thanks for trying it but as it's a run time error I'm fairly convinced it's a asp issue. I've not been able to reproduce it on a simple example using the F# mvc template, but I'm unable to post the broken code for business reasons. I'll keep investigating it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have DataAccess and FitnessController defined in the same assembly or different assemblies?

If they are defined in different assemblies then this error is almost certainly caused by the assembly that contains FitnessController being compiled against one version of the assembly that contains DataAccess but at runtime a different version is loaded.

This could happen for a number of reasons, the two that I can think of off the top of my head are:

- a version of the assembly containing DataAccess is deployed to the gac. The .NET assembly loader always uses the version deployed in the GAC if it exists and it's fairly easy for the version in the GAC to get out of sync with the latest development version.
- the version of the assembly containing DataAccess isn't being copied into the bin directory of the asp.net project when your code is compiled.

Is this happen in your development environment or in production? If it's in your development environment it should be fairly easy to debug, simple run the project in debug mode then use the Debug > Windows > Modules window to see where the two assemblies are being loaded from. Once you know that it should be fairly easy to see where the problem comes from.

Alternatively it may just be easier DataAccess and FitnessController into the same assembly.

Comment: Hi Robert,
Thanks for the tip I didn't know that window existed. Unfortunately it does show that all the dll's have been loaded. If I copy the module code into the same assembly it does work however. Clearing out the temporary asp.net folder didn't work either.

Comment: Hi Dylan, that seems to suggest to me that the wrong version of the assembly is being loaded. I would clean you temp asp.net files and ensure you delete all copies of the assembly containing DataAccess from your source tree. You'll probably find after that your project won't build because one of your reference, probably in the asp.net project is point to the wrong place. Hopefully then it'll just be a matter of correcting them.

Comment: Aside: if it works with everything in the same assembly then why not just do that? It's often unnecessary to split small and even medium sized projects into lots of different assemblies.

Comment: I think I might try and combine the assemblies. It's a habit from working on too many enterprise apps. Thanks you've put me on the right track at least.

Comment: so it looks like the FSharp.core dll wasn't referenced from the MVC web project. I'm using VS 11 dev preview so it was hankering after version 4.3 which may have been causing extra problems.